# @Ajax.Actionlink render partialview

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am trying to use Ajax.Actionlink to render a partial view. But it only redirects me to the partial view. I also added: `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` to webconfig.  Anyone?

**My layout.cshtml** Scripts.render and script is in head tag. Ajax.actionlink and div is in body

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jqueries")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



@Ajax.ActionLink("Ajax Click", "Document","Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })

<div id="result">

</div>
```

**Home controller:**

```
public PartialViewResult Document()
     {

                return PartialView("Document", om);
     }
```

**My Document.cshtml**

```
@model mymodel


@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.something, "Controller", "Action")</li>
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your jquery and unobtrusive-ajax should be at the bottom of the page, like this

```
</footer>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Information why can be found here
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/
Placing this at the wrong place, WILL result in errors

Comment: Would vote it but need 15reputation :P It did work, thank you!

Comment: Would u may explain why it has to be like this? Do i need to this every time I'm using javascript?

Comment: Information why can be found here http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/ Placing this at the wrong place, WILL result in errors